# Attached java code does not print German Characters in output correctly on Windows 2008 R2 German Locale

Tags: java, unicode, runtime.exec

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;



public class ping1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static String feedback = "";

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(feedback);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ta);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Test1");
        Runtime rTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p;


        try{
            p = rTime.exec("ping 10.11.11.67");
            InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
            InputStream stderr = p.getErrorStream();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout,"UTF-8"));
            StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            char sch = 13;  // check for ^M character
            char dch = '\n';    // replace ^m by next line character

            while (line != null) { 
                line = reader.readLine();

                if (line != null){

                    line = new String(line.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
                    //System.out.println("line after :"+line);
                    data.append(line.replace(sch, dch));        // 7.1.00 AMTRAK QM001531720
                }       
                data.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            // notify listeners if feedback is not suppressed
            ping1.feedback = data.toString();

            System.out.println("Data in feebback:"+ping1.feedback.toString());


//            System.out.println("Output stream:"+strout );
//            System.out.println("Error stream:"+strerr );

        }
        catch(IOException npe){
            System.out.println(npe.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

I need output should be exactly as the ping command provided on this box instead it gives me output with ? 
for e.g. output of ping on command window starts with 
Ping wird ausgeführt für 10.11.11.67 mit 32 Bytes Daten:

but when i run this from code i get

Ping wird ausgef?hrt f?r 10.11.11.67 mit 32 Bytes Daten:

Check für and f?r

Comment: What codepage is your console using?

Comment: With the help of this link output of eclipse console was changed to UTF-8 - http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.in/2014/01/changing-eclipse-console-encoding-to-output-unicode.html

Comment: try not to put the test result to windows console but write that to a file, see commons-io / FileUtils

Answer (score 0):

it might be the jvm encoding causing this problem. Try setting in the environment variables (Computer->Properties->advanced System Setings-> new variable)

variable name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
variable value: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Comment: After setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS instead of ? for we get Square box.